# How to group by user id to a specific row?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select the unique user id that is going to a specific user.

let's say I want it to be 200,000 rows from 10M rows.
I want only only 1500 unique user id with around 200,000 rows(the rows does not need to be specific a few thousands is okay).
Each user has multiple ratings.

Here's the dataset [link](https://grouplens.org/datasets/movielens/10m/).

How I load the data.

```
names = ['user_id', 'movie_id', 'rating', 'timestamp']
df = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv', sep='::', names=names)
print(df)
```

Is there any way to group it like that with pandas?

Comment: you can use the pandas df.isin() method. EDIT: Sorry, didnt seen, that there was a post before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test the real dataset, but the logic should be something like:

```
# select 1500 unique users
import numpy as np
users = np.random.choice(df['user_id'].unique(), size=1500, replace=False)

# filter the users and get (up to) 200k random rows
df_sample = df[df['user_id'].isin(users)].sample(n=200000)
```

documentations: [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and [`pandas.DataFrame.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html.)

Comment: I am getting this error ```TypeError: random_sample() got multiple values for keyword argument 'size'```

Comment: Yes this was a typo, the command is choice, not sample (already updated)